# Calculating the quantity and price from 2 different tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, ordertable (which the user uses to add orders and calculate) and product which contains the price per unit for certain products. What should happen in theory when a user presses a calculate button is the quantity which the user entered will be multiplied against the cost of the product they are selling. The query can work on the mysql console so it's to do with how i'm trying to input it into the textfield.

Below is my query.

```
public void calculateOrder(ActionEvent event){

String total = totalBox.getText();

String queryUpdate="UPDATE ordertable o JOIN product p ON p.productID = o.productID set o.total = o.amount * p.cost";
 String updateBox="SELECT total FROM ordertable";
try{

    query=c.prepareStatement(queryUpdate);
    query=c.prepareStatement(updateBox);
    query.setString(1, total);
    //query.setString(2, productID);
    query.execute();


       query.close();
        rs.close();

    Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Calculated");

    confirmation.show();

}

 catch(SQLException e){

     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

}

Below is the error.
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: whats the exception? I bet its complaining about this SUM(o.quantity * p.cost). Does mysql support the * operator as multiplication?

Comment: this is the exception.

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Isn't this a fundamentally bad design, in that if a product price is changed, then the values of orders (regardless of order status) are changed? Shouldn't the price of the product *at time of order* also be copied to the order table, so that people pay what they expect when they order, and not the price that the product is set at at some later date?

Comment: SET =(SELECT SUM(o.quantity * p.cost), what are you setting? shouldnt there be a column name after SET

Comment: I have a textfield box that i'm trying to set. 

Yea it is bad design being honest. I'm just trying to start of from the basics and build out.

Comment: But if you have all the data in a single table (*orders*) doesn't this negate this issue? (although I admit this sort of issue will need to be addressed at some point)

Comment: The query is plain wrong. It's missing a parenthesis, you don't have a `WHERE` clause which means that you will UPDATE all records in your table, and your parameter `cost` is not defined. A lot of things in summary...

Comment: Okay well i'll have a shot at trying to fix that with your advice

Comment: I've updated my code with my bad solution so far and it still isn't working

Comment: Does the same query work when it's run in MySQL console? Or what errors do you see?

Comment: what is the output from System.out.println(e) ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your Query has an issue.  If I recall correctly in your usage, o.quantity is not known within the nested query.    Try reformatting it as follows:

```
UPDATE ordertable o 
INNER JOIN products p 
        ON p.productionID = o.productionID
set o.cost =  o.quantity * p.price
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of defining types of joins, leavig no ambiguity, so the above would be an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Fair enough, I prefer to take advantage of MySQL's shorter syntax... but for clarity I can type this as INNER JOIN

Comment: This works a charm on the mysql console but i can't get it to output to my textfield. But thankyou very much for the help!

Comment: It's always worth bearing in mind that many people viewing Stack Overflow are not the geniuses that you and I are, and may not realised what an undefined `JOIN` is `:-)`

Comment: J.Doe does that mean you are no longer getting an SQL exception now?   If you are still getting it please share what it says.   Also I'm no programming expert at all.. but don't you at some point need to set a variable = to the response from your .execute() method?

Comment: this is the error

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).